# Everyday Low-Energy Atom Collider

Tags: friction, atomic-physics

During the shearing of metal in a machining process, what exactly is the source of the heat that is produced? I realize that the energy is coming from the work being done by the cutting tool. I am interested in hearing what happens at a molecular/atomic/sub-atomic scale.  Do the atoms near the cut surfaces get pushed close together causing interactions which generate radiation of infra-red wavelengths (or possibly visible wavelengths if the parts become glowing red)?  Is this like a very low energy level particle collider? Is friction of all sorts like this?

Comment: "is this like a very low energy particle collider". If you define as "particle" the molecules bonded in the material, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Various physical properties of materials including shear strength are connected to the strength of attractive forces between molecules -inter-molecular forces. The type of inter-molecular force determines the force and energy by which the molecules stick to one another. Inter-molecular force types include ionic bonds, hydrogen bonds, dipole forces and induced dipole forces. For metals the binding energy is in induced dipoles where the 'sea' of electrons are constantly interchanged between atomic nuclei.  The interchange induces temporary dipole forces between the nuclei. By mechanically separating layers of atoms within the lattice, such as is done in machining of metals, the binding energies are released in the form of heat.